# php creating file from another file

Tags: php

Im new to php and I'm just trying stuff out, and I was wondering if i could take text from one file then put it into another.
For example have a .txt file that contains :

```
<?php
      echo "Hello World";
?>
```

but then have a script run that takes that text and puts it into a new .php file.

Comment: I don't get what you are tring to do, Its better to tell us, what you are planning to achive with that, maybe we can offer an better idea.

Comment: @VuralAcar i was wondering if i can take the content of one file then write it to another file using php

Comment: You want to get the content from a text file and copy to another text file?

Comment: @VuralAcar copy it to a php file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have php code in that file you also could just use:

```
Include 'example.php';
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, what are you trying to achive is copying a content of a text file to a php file.

Simpliest way to do it:

```
<?php
   $sourceFile = 'example.txt';
   $destinyFile = 'example.php';

   if (copy($sourceFile, $destinyFile))
      echo "DONE";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this.